# Get value from next row in Excel sheet with POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, import-from-excel

I'm using Apache POI to read an Excel document. I want to get the cell value from the next row if current is empty. For example, get from first row all not empty cell values and for empty cells: move to the next row and get the value.
This the code I'm using to read the Excel document

```
                //every sheet has rows, iterate over them
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

                if (rowIterator.hasNext())
                    rowIterator.next();

                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
                {

                    String libelle="";
                    .....

                    //Get the row object
                    Row row = rowIterator.next();

                    //Every row has columns, get the column iterator and iterate over them
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                    {
                        //Get the Cell object
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                        //check the cell type and process accordingly
                        //2nd column

                        switch(cell.getCellType()){
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                            ......
                            if (row.getCell(5) == null)
                            {
                               System.out.println("Cell is Empty in Column:" );

                            } else if (row.getCell(5).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                            {
                            libelle= row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue().trim();
                            }
```

...

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI docs on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Sheet.getRow(int rownumber)` to get a row with a specific number.
You can get the current row's number via `Row.getRowNum()` and the cell's index via `Cell.getColumnIndex()`.

Therefore, the value of the cell in the next row would be

```
Row nextRow = sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum() + 1);
if (nextRow != null)
    String value = nextRow.getCell(curCel.getColumnIndex(), Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the current [Cell.getRowIndex()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getRowIndex%28%29) to access the next `Row` via the [Sheet.getRow(int)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow%28int%29) method if the calculated index is smaller than [Sheet.getLastRowNum()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getLastRowNum%28%29) in order to access [Cell.getColumnIndex()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getColumnIndex%28%29) of the `Cell` of the following `Row`.